# Date SQL Between

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to sort the result of my SQL Query by date with a WHERE.
I want to know how can i get the result between the actual date and 6 month before.

Something like

```
BETWEEN actual_date
AND actual_date - (operator) 6 month
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi, You should approve a answer if one of them was correct.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE actual_date BETWEEN DATE_ADD(Now(),INTERVAL -6 MONTH) AND Now()
```

Had a inital error, since its 6 months back, the lower date should be first.

Comment: It would make more sense from a readability point of view to use [`DATE_SUB`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub) with a positive interval

Comment: Wow im a bit embarrased as i never used `DATE_SUB`, i Always added a - for subtraction. Guess habits are hard to kick. But yes, for readability `DATE_SUB` makes more sense. Upvoted Niels's answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
WHERE mydate BETWEEN DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH) AND NOW()
```

1. [Date_sub information](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub)

Comment: Need to switch the dates there as between now and 6 months in the past returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

i am not in front of a MySQL Terminal but this should work

```
select 
  *
from
  yourtable t
where
  /* Greater or equal NOW */
  r.date >= NOW() 
  /* Smaller or equal than 6 months ago */
  r.date <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE actual_date BETWEEN DATE_ADD(actual_date,INTERVAL -6 MONTH) AND actual_date

or 

SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE actual_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB( actual_date, INTERVAL 6 MONTH) AND actual_date
```